# After Magento 2.3 to 2.4 upgrade Category page not loading in frontend

Tags: category, catalog, image

Magento 2.4 upgraded successfully. All are working in admin and storefront but only problem with category page showing error

" Error: Call to a member function getUrl() on null in /home/mydomain.com/dqgdqtpdwx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/image.phtml:21 Stack trace: #0

/home/mydomain.com/dqgdqtpdwx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(71): include() #1 "

I can access product page but issue with category page access after show in above error.
This issue solve any tips please share with me. Thanks for advance

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30753

Comment: May this can help!